# PHP to output single and double quotes as a value for an input element

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have a value ($title) that is stored in MySQL and is being called, using PHP, to be inserted into the value of an input element. The problem is when a single or double quote is used, the value of the input field terminates at that point.

The behavior that should occur is the input field should be populated EXACTLY with the data in the $title variable, so that when the form is updated, the quotes remain intact.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    echo '<input type=text size=91 name=title value="'.stripslashes($title).'">';
?>
```

Now, here is a typical problem: if the value of $title

```
this is a test " of what occurs with a quote
```

and I echo the variable, it echos correctly to

```
this is a test " of what occurs with a quote
```

However, when used in an input field, it renders as:

```
<input value="this is a test " of what occurs with a quote">
```

The first " terminates the value of the field, causing the new value to be:

```
this is a test
```

I'm confused as to how to get the proper value to display and be submitted with the form, when that variable is displayed and updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). This will escape the " in yout title.

```
value="'.htmlspecialchars($title).'">
```

Comment: This is excellent! Now how to I get it to not error out if an apostrophe is inserted into the input field?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment. What error do you get when inserting an apostrophe.

Comment: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'This is the description updated "with" quotes', date_of_call='06/11/2013', time_' at line 1

Comment: You also have to use htmlspecialchars when inserting the value into the database.
So use "INSERT INTO table (id, .., title) VALUES (NULL, ..., htmlspecialchars($object->getTitle()))"
Hope this helps.

Comment: That's an SQL error, meaning you're WIDE OPEN to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do NOT use this buggy code in production, or your server + site are going to get utterly destroyed.

Comment: Well, yes, that actually makes a lot of sense. I'm just having a hard time finding where (this is someone else's code) the value is inserted to modify it that way. Thank you for the help, though, this is just what I needed. Is there any other way to redefine $title after the form is submitted, and before the INSERT INTO command is run?

Comment: @MarcB Actually, that has been pointed out -- the code is VERY old! The good news is that this is used only by a few people, and on an intranet (completely inaccessible to the outside world, and no bad guys in the group using it :-)

Comment: No... don't use htmlspecialchars when inserting data into the database.  Use mysql_real_escape_string instead.

Comment: Is there any way to redefine the variable with either mysql_real_escape_string or htmlspecialchars (whichever will work) after the form is filled out, so that that will be the value inserted into the database?

Answer (score 2):

Put a `\` before the quote.

`echo "This is a \" test";`

Comment: I had a similar case, I did not need to use htmlspecialchar or stripslashes or addslashes, simply escaping the quotes or double-quotes surrounding the variable for the value.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line.

```
<input type=text size=91 name=title value="'.stripslashes($title).'">
```

To

```
<input type=text size=91 name=title value=\''.stripslashes($title).'\'>
```

Comment: then use htmlspecialchars with that.

Answer (score 0):

After you perform `stripslashes` you should use `htmlspecialchars` to escape the special characters. This avoids the mess the characters like ",', etc might otherwise create.

```
<input type=text size=91 name=title value="'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($title)).'">
```

The above snippet will only fix it for display purpose. But when the submit happens you must use either `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `$pdo->quote()` to escape the special characters before you run the SQL query.

Comment: This, too, works. However, I'm getting a MySQL error when an apostrophe is used in the input box. Any idea how to clear that up?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` above only escapes the data for display purpose. before performing an insert into MySQL, perform `htmlspecialchars` again.

Comment: No no no.  Don't use htmlspecialchars to insert into the database.  Ugh.  Horrible horrible advice.

Comment: @dihakz @bobwienholt is correct. You should instead use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [`$pdo->quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: Thank you all for the help -- now I'm just trying to get my value submitted to escape single quotes for insertion into the database. Then I'm golden! :-)

Comment: @dihakz mysql_real_escape_string() will escape single quotes (and all other special characters) for inserting into the database.

Comment: @bobwienholt would I simply use `$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running `stripslashes()`?  Running `addslashes()` (the opposite function) would fix this particular issue, but a better approach would be to use `htmlentities($title, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')` everywhere you output the title (or, if your structure allows, when the data is stored).

Comment: When I try this, I get only 'This' in my input field, when the value of $title is actually 'This is a test of the title field. It contains a double quote " " "' (single quote is not actually part of the strings, I only used that to show where the string started and ended.)